# How to save to png multiple plots created at one R script

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I have few separate plots in one R script that I'd like to save to png files. I run the script at the terminal and out of the 4 plots, only the last one was created as png file.

How to fix it so it will create and save all 4 plots as png files?

```
library(data.table)
library("ggplot2")

setwd("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\R\\figure_1A-D")

final_df_older <- fread("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\R\\older.csv"), 
                        select=c(3,4))

png("Figure 1a - older_samples.png", width = 500, height = 400)


figure_1_wo_new <- ggplot(data = final_df_older, aes(x=final_df_older$`quntity`, y=final_df_older$`count`))

dev.off()
list.files(pattern = "png")
getwd()


final_df_all <- fread("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\R\\all.csv"), 
                        select=c(3,4))


png("Figure 1b - all)samples.png", width = 500, height = 400)


figure_1_all <- ggplot(data = final_df_all, aes(x=final_df_all$`quntity`, y=final_df_all$`count`))


dev.off()
list.files(pattern = "png")
getwd()


final_df_new <- fread("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\R\\new.csv"), 
                        select=c(3,4))

png("Figure 1c - new_samples.png", width = 500, height = 400)


figure_1_new_only <- ggplot(data = final_df_new, aes(x=final_df_new$`quntity`, y=final_df_new$`count`))


dev.off()
list.files(pattern = "png")
getwd()

library("gridExtra")
library("grid")

png("Figure 1d - merged_plot.png", width = 1500, height = 500)

merged_plot <- grid.arrange(figure_1_wo_new, figure_1_all,figure_1_new_only, ncol=3,
                        top = textGrob("Merged plot",
                                       gp=gpar(fontsize=30,font=3,cex=1,col="darksalmon"),vjust=0.4))
dev.off()
list.files(pattern = "png")
getwd()
```

Comment: The ggplot2 function `ggsave()` can replace then png() and dev.off() pattern. For example, `ggsave("figure.png", plot_name, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)`. As an extra bonus, the plot_name does not have to be declared, and the most recently created ggplot plot will be used.

Comment: why all the `getwd()`?

Comment: The ggsave() need to come after the creation of the plot?